# Eclipse : Share stegano image to another app with Intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, steganography

I have image steganography app for android. The main function of this app have worked well, such as encoding, decoding, and save images in phone storage.

But, I want a picture that has been inserted a secret message can be shared with other app like Whatsapp, Facebook, Twitter. After I try to make the share button and click the button, I was not given a choice application where I will share those images.

However, I was directed to the MMS message. although the MMS message can work well, but I want to be able to choose the app where I will share images.

This is a part of encoding code where assosiated with share  button :

```
    Button buttonShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    buttonShare.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            closeContextMenu();
            closeOptionsMenu();
            progressBar=new MobiProgressBar(EncodeActivity.this);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            progressBar.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.encoding));
            progressBar.show();
            Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Uri uri= encode();                      
                    ShareIntent share=new ShareIntent(uri,EncodeActivity.this);
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    share.send();
                }
            });
            tt.start();
        }
    });
```

And this code for share method :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class ShareIntent {
private Uri uri;    
private final Context context;

public Uri getUri() {
    return uri;
}

public void setUri(Uri uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}   

public ShareIntent(Uri uri,Context context) {       
    this.uri = uri;
    this.context=context;
}

public void send()
{
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));
}
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Quick question. Does your algorithm work for lossy images? More specifically, do you embed the secret in the least significant bits of the image pixels?

Comment: yup that's right, I use Least Significant Bits.

Comment: In that case, I think your biggest worry is whether the image is reencoded to jpeg when uploaded to the social media, because that'll destroy your secret.

Comment: How with lossless image formats such as PNG?

Comment: Your image can be whatever format you want on your computer, but it's reencoded when it's uploaded to some sites. Even for minimal information loss the size compression is really worth it. I have only verified this with Facebook, but I expect others sites to do the same.

Comment: But, if I share with email and bluetooth. the image will not change, right?
So, please help me to fix the code so that shows other application if I click the share button.
thank you for all your answers. regrads: D

Comment: Email attachment and bluetooth should transfer the file as is, so you should be good there. Unfortnuately, I don't know how to help you with either that or the share functionality. I just pointed out the above caveat in case you spent a lot of time on it, only to realise it neutralises your secret communication.

Comment: ok. no problem..
thanks for your help..